# Give a rank depending on values

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, sorting, rank

I have a small problem an hoped you can help me with. A list of mine conatains values and also several empty rows between them. Now I need to give a Rank for each Value.
So for example my values are 5, 7 and 10. They would have the ranks 1 (5), 2 (7) and 3 (10)
In the same row as 5 the rank 1 should be written in another column.

I have an idea of an solution but it dont seems very practical:
- go through the list and store all values in an array
-Sort the array (somehow)
- go through each line again and if the first value in the array is found, write 1 as rank
-go through each line and write 2 where the second value is found, write 2 as rank
-continue for each element in array

This doesnt seem to be smart or quick way to solve my issue.
Also I would need to figure out how to sort an array.

I read about the "Rank" method but Iam unsure how to use it.

```
Dim RankingArray As Variant
Dim a As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim x As Integer

a = 0
x = 0
ReDim RankingArray(a) As String 

For i = 1 to LastRow
RankingArray(a) = Cells(i,5).value 
    a = a + 1
    ReDim Preserve ArrDoneME(a) As String

Next i

'Sort Array magically

a = 0

For j = LBound(RankingArray) To UBound(RankingArray)
     For i = 1 to LastRow
         If RankingArray(j) = Cells(i,5).value 
            x = x + 1
            cells(i,4).value = x
         End if
     Next i
Next j
```

Comment: Why aren't you using formula?

Comment: List gets filled by different imports and grows or shrinks, dependingly. Also the values are insert by a makro already so i guess it would make sense to use vba.
Lets say its a complex enviorment ^^